# Pass Excel-Workbook-Reference through VBA to C# Com Interop Type Library

Tags: c#, excel, vba, macros, interop

I have a C# Program which reads **AND** writes data from and to the same Excel File using Microsoft Interop (and afterwards do stuff with the data, e.g. exporting it to another interface).

So basically I have a class 'ExcelFileReader' in my Project, which opens the ExcelFile, read and write data, and close the file afterwards.

Code Snippet:

```
m_ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
m_ExcelWorkBook = m_ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(m_ExcelPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

As you can see, the third argument from the .open Method is false, which means 'readonly=false' (because as I already mentioned, I need to write data to the file). Hence, when I run my program, the Excel-File has to be closed.

What I want to do now, is writing an VBA Macro (included in my Excel-File), that starts my programm (and of course also read and write data to my now open Excel File). I know how to include the *.tlb file in Excel.

**But what (I think) I need to do is something like passing a reference from the open Excel-File to my Application?!?**

Do you have any ideas if this is possible and if so how I can do that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! And it's not complicated!

In VBA it's possible to pass for example the reference for the workbook as a parameter in a method. So what I basically did, is passing the reference of the workbook to my TypeLibrary. And in my C#-Program I did not open my ExcelFile anymore but simply wrote

```
m_ExcelWorkBook = parameter_WorkBook;
```

That's it.

So yes. It is possible to pass an Excel-Workbook-Reference to a Type Library and work with it!

Comment: don't you have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70578619/5592493)?